# Get the difference between two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got two arrays of objects, the difference between them is only that arrayAfter will have an element added:

```
var arrayBefore = [
  {"name":"Alan","height":"171","weight":"66"},
  {"name":"Ben","height":"182","weight":"90"}
 ];

var arrayAfter= [
  {"name":"Alan","height":"171","weight":"66"},
  {"name":"Ben","height":"182","weight":"90"},
  {"name":"Chris","height":"163","weight":"71"}
 ];
```

"name" is always unique!

How can I find out which one is the element that has been added? I've tried ending up using nested for loops, but this seems overcomplicated.

I've also found the this nice idea:

```
var diff = $(arrayAfter).not(arrayBefore ).get();
```

However, that does not seem to work on arrays of objects straight ahead.

**Is there some easy way to get the difference?**

Comment: You'd have to compare the name, height, and weight to find the differences. No magic method.

Comment: I'd like a jquery solution and I know that name will always be unique..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only the name indicates uniqueness, you can do:

```
//Get a list of all the names in the before array
var beforeNames = arrayBefore.map(function(person) { return person.name });

//Filter the after array to only contain names not contained in the before array
var uniqueObjects = arrayAfter.filter(function(person) {
    return beforeNames.indexOf(person.name) === -1;
});

console.log(uniqueObjects); //[{"name":"Chris","height":"163","weight":"71"}]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tehgc8L5/

Comment: Very cool and exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.

Comment: This works fine, but note that for large data sets, the array lookup (`indexOf`) will perform poorly. Using object properties should speed things up: http://jsbin.com/nakugapoga/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

For a generic method you can combine [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) which iterates over the object keys:

```
arrayAfter.filter(function(after) {
    return !arrayBefore.reduce(function(found, before) {
        if (!found) {
            found = true;
            for (key in before) {
                if (before.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    found = found && (before[key] === after[key]);
                }
            }
        }
        return found;
    }, false);
}); //[{name: "Chris", height: "163", weight: "71"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and filter out those elements in the previous array.

```
var differences = arrayAfter.filter(function(el) {
  return arrayBefore.indexOf(el) === -1;
});
```

Comment: Did I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: @Grimbode It works if both arrays contain the same instances of the objects. Whether that's true or not was not made clear.

Comment: @MikeC they have the same data but are not the same, try `({}) === ({})`

Comment: @Hacketo I understand how object comparisons work. What I'm saying is that this solution works fine if, say, `arrayAfter` is the result of copying `arrayBefore` and pushing other objects into it.

Comment: You can compare arrays of objects by value, by converting every object in both arrays to json. Then this `.indexOf` search will succeed. It's kinda slow, but easy to code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe jQuery will have nothing that will directly solve your problem here. Your problem being comparing objects for equality.

I am assuming that name is unique. If not, for this method you will need a unique identifier for data. If you absolute do not have one then you could concat all data to get one.

```
// first make a map of objects in before
var before = {};
arrayBefore.forEach(function(o){
   before[o.name] = o;
});

// now we get the elements of after that do not exist in our hashmap
var result = arrayAfter.filter(function(o){
    return !(o.name in before);
});
```

You can obviously wrap this up in a general function.